# What is the difference between using @ServerEndpoint and @MessageMapping for a websocket communication in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, endpoint, spring-websocket

For websocket communication in Spring Boot, I'm confused if I should use @MessageMapping or @ServerEndpoint. Any clear explanation with use case examples!

Enable real-time communication between server and client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both **@MessageMapping** and **@ServerEndpoint** annotations can be used for real-time communication between server and client using WebSockets in Spring Boot, but they serve slightly different purposes and have different use cases.

**@MessageMapping** is part of Spring's STOMP (Simple Text Oriented Messaging Protocol) support, which provides an abstraction over the WebSocket protocol. It allows you to handle WebSocket messages on the server side by annotating methods with @MessageMapping, which maps a specific message type to a particular method. For example, if the client sends a message with the destination "/app/hello", you can create a method in your controller annotated with @MessageMapping("/hello") to handle it. @MessageMapping is commonly used when you want to implement a WebSocket endpoint in your Spring Boot application that provides a messaging functionality to clients, such as a chat application or a real-time data dashboard.

**@ServerEndpoint**, on the other hand, is a standard WebSocket endpoint in Java EE that you can use to create WebSocket endpoints in your Spring Boot application. It allows you to handle WebSocket connections and messages at a low level, by defining a WebSocket endpoint class that extends javax.websocket.Endpoint and annotating it with @ServerEndpoint. For example, you can define a WebSocket endpoint class that handles incoming messages by implementing the onMessage method. @ServerEndpoint is commonly used when you want to implement a custom WebSocket endpoint in your Spring Boot application that provides specific functionality to clients, such as real-time gaming or video streaming.

In summary, if you want to provide a messaging functionality to clients, you can use **@MessageMapping** with Spring's STOMP support. If you want to implement a custom WebSocket endpoint with low-level control over the WebSocket connections and messages, you can use @ServerEndpoint.

Comment: I'm about to use the annotation ServerEndpoint in real-time data dashboard. Should I use the annotation  MessageMapping instead ? I tried both ways but there are always problems in sending data from the server or receiving data by the client.